# Define symmetric relation R on set S

Tags: relations

Answer: A symmetric relation R on S is that For all $x,y\in S$ such that $xRy$ implies $yRx$. meaning if the element x is related to  y, then it is also true the other way around that element y is related to x of the set S.

i.e. $xRy\rightarrow yRx$

Does my definition wordings correct?

Comment: correct, but better use $\forall$ symbol: $\forall x,y\in S(xRy\rightarrow yRx)$

Comment: can I get a basic home work question of the above relation to solve?

Comment: A nice HW practice question: prove that if $R$ is a non empty symmetric and transitive relation over $S$, then it must be reflexive.